# momentjs equivalent of PHP's date()

Tags: momentjs

What's the momentjs (JavaScript) equivalent of
PHP : `<?php echo date('D, M d Y') ?>`
JavaScript : `new moment("2020-04-02 11:00:00").format('D, M d Y')`
I can't do much formatting natively with `.toDateString()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP's `date()` and `momentjs.format()` uses other format options;

```
PHP     MOMENT      ?
D       ddd         Mon through Sun
M       MMM         Jan through Dec
d       DD          Mon through Sun
Y       YYYY        2020
```

[PHP date docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) -- 
 [MomentJSFormat docs](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/)

```js
const mom = new moment('2020-04-02 11:00:00');
console.log(mom.format('ddd, MMM DD YYYY'));   // Thu, Apr 02 2020
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the doc link. I guess what I need is `.format('ddd, MMM Do YYYY')`

Comment: @PlanBuildr Your welkom, I hope this answers your question. PHP's `d` is the same as momentjs `DD` if you want 01-31.